# Do I draw a new hand if I start my turn without any card?

Tags: munchkin

I played with a new group of friends recently and they are playing with such a rule where they will draw a new hand if they don't have any card. Basically their strategy is to finish off all the cards in their hand so they can draw a new 4x treasures and 4x doors the next turn. Any idea if this true? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you do not draw a new hand when yours runs out. Your friends are playing with a house rule. It *might* be an optional rule in some expansion's handbook, but I'm not aware of such an optional rule.

The only time you draw a new hand is when you start a new character: at the beginning of the game, or after you die.

You are *not expected* to always have cards in your hand in Munchkin. In fact, it's highly likely that you won't have any cards in your hand a while into the game, and that's fine!

Comment: I don't remember seeing this rule anywhere in the first eight expansions.

Answer (score 5):

**No, you do not draw 4 cards from the Treasure or Door deck when you empty your hand.**

The [official rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf) mention '4' seven times, and 'four' twice. All the '4' references are examples (I.e. [general rules list] "**4. You must kill** a monster to reach Level 10," [phase] "**(4) Charity**: If you have more than five cards in your hand," "Drooling Slime and an Elf helps you, the monster’s combat strength is **increased by 4**," etc. ). The two places 'four' are mentioned is in the **Setup** and **Death** sections. These are the only rules that allow you to draw four cards from both the Treasure and Door decks.

> **Setup** - [...] Divide the cards into the Door deck and the Treasure deck. Shuffle both decks. **Deal four cards from each deck to each player.** (page 1)
>
> **Death** - [...] Your new character appears when the next player begins his turn, and can help others in combat . . . but you have no cards.
> On your next turn, start by **drawing four cards from each deck**, face-down, and playing any legal Race, Class, or Item cards you want to, just as when you started the game. Then take your turn normally. (page 3)